# Stored procedure from Oracle doesn't work with Entity Framework database-first workflow

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ef-database-first

I have a problem when I try to call a stored procedure from Oracle. I could correctly import the stored procedure which was mapped to a function which I called `AddVideo`, but when running this function it throws a `System.ArgumentException` exception that I do not know why it can be.

This is my stored procedure in Oracle:

```
create or replace procedure SP_ADD_VIDEO
     (p_name in varchar2, p_release_date in date, p_genre in varchar2)
is
    genreId number;
    maxVideoId number;
begin
  select G.ID into genreId
  from GENRES G
  where G.NAME = p_genre;

  insert into VIDEOS(ID, NAME, RELEASEDATE)
  values(SEQ_VIDEOS.NEXTVAL, p_name, p_release_date);

  select MAX(V.ID) into maxVideoId
  from VIDEOS V;

  insert into VIDEOGENRES(VIDEOID,GENREID)
  values(maxVideoId,genreId);
end SP_ADD_VIDEO;
```

And this is my mapped function:

```
public virtual int AddVideo(string p_NAME, Nullable<System.DateTime> p_RELEASE_DATE, string p_GENRE)
{
    var p_NAMEParameter = p_NAME != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("P_NAME", p_NAME) :
        new ObjectParameter("P_NAME", typeof(string));

    var p_RELEASE_DATEParameter = p_RELEASE_DATE.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("P_RELEASE_DATE", p_RELEASE_DATE) :
        new ObjectParameter("P_RELEASE_DATE", typeof(System.DateTime));

    var p_GENREParameter = p_GENRE != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("P_GENRE", p_GENRE) :
        new ObjectParameter("P_GENRE", typeof(string));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("AddVideo", p_NAMEParameter, p_RELEASE_DATEParameter, p_GENREParameter);
}
```

And this is where I call the `AddVideo` function to insert the given values as parameters into the stored procedure:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dbContext = new VidzyDbContext();
        dbContext.AddVideo("Gladiator", DateTime.Today, "Action");
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me solve this problem.

Comment: I have 0 exp with oracle, but try renaming your parameters in your AddViedeo method to lowercase.  E,g, "P_NAME" -> "p_name".  Since these are the names of your parameters in your sproc.

Comment: The name of your procedure is `SP_ADD_VIDEO` and your call has `AddVideo`, I believe this line should read: `return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("SP_ADD_VIDEO", p_NAMEParameter, p_RELEASE_DATEParameter, p_GENREParameter);`

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if it would work for Oracle, but in MSSQL, you'd have to do this:

```
return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction(
    "SP_ADD_VIDEO @P_NAME, @P_RELEASE_DATE, @P_GENRE",
    p_NAMEParameter, p_RELEASE_DATEParameter, p_GENREParameter);
```

When you do create your parameters, continue not putting the @ when you do `new ObjectParameter...` though.

I always had my parameters names with the same casing in the code as in the database, so I'm not sure if you should adjust to lowercase in the code to match the database or not.

Comment: In the past, I've only been able to get calls to stored procedures to work with a mix of `@` and `:`.  Use a `@` before defining the paramater, and a `:` before the variable name.  

So I call Oracle EF stored procedures like so: 

`OracleParameter[] oSQLParams =
{
 new OracleParameter("@p_name", "Gladiator"),
 new OracleParameter("@p_release_date", DateTime.Today),
 new OracleParameter("@p_genre", "Action"),
};

string sSQL = "begin SP_ADD_VIDEO(:p_name, :p_release_date, :p_genre); end;";

db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sSQL, oSQLParams);`